# A better Media LIbrary Experience

Tags: custom-taxonomy, media-library

I've spent a good amount of time reading through everyone's suggestions about better file management with the Media Library -- and at the end of the day, I haven't come across any clear winners at the moment. I saw [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29858/adding-category-tag-taxonomy-support-to-images-media) question/answer about adding taxonomies to the Media Library -- but it looks like that experience is an open text-field (not incredibly user friendly). Is that the best we'll get with that at the moment. What I would hope for is an experience just like any other taxonomy screen.

I've seen [Custom Upload Directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-upload-dir/) which is falling pray to some PHP errors (so I can't properly test) and [Media Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-categories-2/) which while nice -- doesn't satisfy the needs of adding the media itself. Here's a run-down of what I was looking for:

- Allow categories in the Media Library (once a suitable UI solution is found -- that [initial  answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/29909/9605) looks like it can then provide the ability to sort by a taxonomy
- Add that same category selection-box to the media modal pop-up
- Allow users to filter by a specific category (select or open-text field) based on a taxonomy
- Automatically assign uploaded files a category either based on image-type or post-type

As I typed that it seems like it's more of a wishlist than a proper question to go on here -- but I have tried to do my due diligence in researching beforehand -- just not sure if this will be a clusterf*** of the possible solutions here. Any hints in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: I'm testing [Media Library Assistant](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-assistant/) and seems really interesting. It covers items #1 and #3 of your list. Item #2 is in [this Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/76721/12615).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the media library is long overdue an overhaul, and it seems there are some guys working on it right now. With any luck some changes will make it in to the next release.

Take a look here at some of the slides and the many commments and feedback: http://make.wordpress.org/ui/2012/07/30/media-wireframes/

Comment: Appreciate it - looking forward to what comes of this!