# How to use taxonomies on attachments with the new Media Library?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, attachments, media

WordPress 3.5 changed the media management and now the Media Library edit screen uses the default post type UI. Taxonomies are very useful for WP installs with different users and attachments, giving more possibilities to find the attachment and/or add classification.

I have seen [Can I add a Category Metabox to attachment?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/496/) on WPSE, but is not perfect to use with WP 3.5 and also have no information about the use of custom categories on attachments, not only the categories of posts.

In short: is it possible to add custom category/tags to attachments to use in the Media Library with WP 3.5?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To add the taxonmies from post type post, the default, then it is easy to add taxonmies 'category' and 'tags' with a small plugin liek the source below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Attachment Taxonomies
 * Plugin URI:  
 * Text Domain: attachment_taxonomies
 * Domain Path: /languages
 * Description: 
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      Frank Bültge
 * Author URI:  http://bueltge.de
 * License:     GPLv3
 */


add_action( 'init', 'fb_attachment_taxonomies' );
function fb_attachment_taxonomies() {

    $taxonomies = array( 'category', 'post_tag' ); // add the 2 tax to ...
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $tax ) {
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $tax, 'attachment' ); // add to post type attachment
    }
}
```

For use custom taxonomies on attachments is it important, that you create a custom taxonomy and this to the post type `attachment`, like the follow plugin.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Attachment Taxonomies
 * Plugin URI:  
 * Text Domain: attachment_taxonomies
 * Domain Path: /languages
 * Description: 
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      Frank Bültge
 * Author URI:  http://bueltge.de
 * License:     GPLv3
 */

if ( function_exists( 'add_filter' ) )
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Fb_Attachment_Taxonomies', 'get_object' ) );
/**
 * Add Tags and Categories taxonmies to Attachment with WP 3.5
 */
class Fb_Attachment_Taxonomies {

    static private $classobj;

    /**
     * Constructor, init the functions inside WP
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct() {

        // load translation files
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'localize_plugin' ) );
        // add taxonmies
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'setup_taxonomies' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Handler for the action 'init'. Instantiates this class.
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     * @access  public
     * @return  $classobj
     */
    public function get_object() {

        if ( NULL === self::$classobj ) {
            self::$classobj = new self;
        }

        return self::$classobj;
    }

    /**
     * Localize plugin function.
     *
     * @uses    load_plugin_textdomain, plugin_basename
     * @since   2.0.0
     * @return  void
     */
    public function localize_plugin() {

        load_plugin_textdomain(
            'attachment_taxonomies',
            FALSE,
            dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Setup Taxonomies
     * Creates 'attachment_tag' and 'attachment_category' taxonomies.
     * Enhance via filter `fb_attachment_taxonomies`
     * 
     * @uses    register_taxonomy, apply_filters
     * @since   1.0.0
     * @return  void
     */
    public function setup_taxonomies() {

        $attachment_taxonomies = array();

        // Tags
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Media Tags', 'taxonomy general name', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Media Tag', 'taxonomy singular name', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Media Tags', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Media Tags', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Media Tag', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Media Tag:', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Media Tag', 'attachment_taxonomies' ), 
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Media Tag', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Media Tag', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Media Tag Name', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Media Tags', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical' => FALSE,
            'labels'       => $labels,
            'show_ui'      => TRUE,
            'show_admin_column' => TRUE,
            'query_var'    => TRUE,
            'rewrite'      => TRUE,
        );

        $attachment_taxonomies[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'attachment_tag',
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'args'      => $args
        );

        // Categories
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Media Categories', 'taxonomy general name', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Media Category', 'taxonomy singular name', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Media Categories', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Media Categories', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Media Category', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Media Category:', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Media Category', 'attachment_taxonomies' ), 
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Media Category', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Media Category', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Media Category Name', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Media Categories', 'attachment_taxonomies' ),
        );

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical' => TRUE,
            'labels'       => $labels,
            'show_ui'      => TRUE,
            'query_var'    => TRUE,
            'rewrite'      => TRUE,
        );

        $attachment_taxonomies[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'attachment_category',
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'args'      => $args
        );

        $attachment_taxonomies = apply_filters( 'fb_attachment_taxonomies', $attachment_taxonomies );

        foreach ( $attachment_taxonomies as $attachment_taxonomy ) {
            register_taxonomy(
                $attachment_taxonomy['taxonomy'],
                $attachment_taxonomy['post_type'],
                $attachment_taxonomy['args']
            );
        }

    }

} // end class
```

See the result on the follow screenshot, also the difference - easier as my small words to the source. But the image of my person in the example screenshot is not relevant to the source ;)
[image: Screenshot of edit media in default post type ui with WP 3.5]

**Small hints:** the UI from the modal box to add media on post type is little bid different to the edit screen on post type attachment. The hierarchical taxonmies have only a tree in the edit screen. In the modal box is it a input field and the tax works with comma as seperator. See also [this post](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/attachment-editing-now-with-full-post-edit-ui/) from Helen on the WP Core blog. But see the custom taxonomies for 'tags' and 'categories' also in a screenshot.

[image: Edit attachment in modal box]

Comment: +1+ One more step in discovering Media Library 3.5, the great unknown of 2012!

Comment: A nice addition would be the argument `'show_admin_column' => true`.

Comment: Yes, you have right. I like this parameter in WP 3.6; I use it often with a small helper class, if I use mayn taxonmies: https://github.com/bueltge/WP-Control-Taxonomy

Comment: Frank, don't forget that for attachment taxonomies, you should probably set `update_count_callback` to `_update_generic_term_count`. See updated Codex entry for why: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments

Answer (score 3):

I'll extend Frank's Answer with [Adding a Taxonomy Filter to Admin List for a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/578/12615)

Looking for both things, Media Categories and Taxonomy Filter, I merged Frank's code with [Kaiser's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82315/12615) in that post. Also added an extra touch of mine to add the post type, where the attachment was uploaded, as a Category.

It produces this:

[image: filtering media categories]

```
add_action(
    'plugins_loaded',
    array ( WPSE76720_Attachment_Taxonomies::get_object(), 'plugin_setup' )
);

// BUELTGE/KAISER/RUDOLF
class WPSE76720_Attachment_Taxonomies 
{
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    public $post_type;
    public $taxonomies;

    /**
     * Used for regular plugin work.
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @return  void
     */
    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        // Taxonomies filter
        add_action( 'load-upload.php', array( $this, 'setup' ) );
        // add taxonmies
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'setup_taxonomies' ) );
        add_action( 'add_attachment', array( $this, 'auto_tax' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    /**
     * Constructor, init the functions inside WP
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     * @return  void
     */
    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Handler for the action 'init'. Instantiates this class.
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     * @access  public
     * @return  $instance
     */
    public function get_object() 
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Setup Taxonomies
     * Creates 'attachment_tag' and 'attachment_category' taxonomies.
     * Enhance via filter `fb_attachment_taxonomies`
     * 
     * @uses    register_taxonomy, apply_filters
     * @since   1.0.0
     * @return  void
     */
    public function setup_taxonomies() 
    {
        $attachment_taxonomies = array();
        // Categories
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => __( 'Media Categories', 'b5f-mc' ),
            'singular_name'     => __( 'Media Category', 'b5f-mc' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Media Categories', 'b5f-mc' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Media Categories', 'b5f-mc' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Media Category', 'b5f-mc' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Media Category:', 'b5f-mc' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Media Category', 'b5f-mc' ), 
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Media Category', 'b5f-mc' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Media Category', 'b5f-mc' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Media Category Name', 'b5f-mc' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Media Categories', 'b5f-mc' ),
        );
        $args = array(
            'hierarchical' => TRUE,
            'labels'       => $labels,
            'show_admin_column' => TRUE,
            'show_ui'      => TRUE,
            'query_var'    => TRUE,
            'rewrite'      => TRUE,
        );
        $attachment_taxonomies[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'attachment_category',
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'args'      => $args
        );
        $attachment_taxonomies = apply_filters( 'fb_attachment_taxonomies', $attachment_taxonomies );
        foreach ( $attachment_taxonomies as $attachment_taxonomy ) {
            register_taxonomy(
                $attachment_taxonomy['taxonomy'],
                $attachment_taxonomy['post_type'],
                $attachment_taxonomy['args']
            );
        }
    }

    public function setup()
    {
        add_action( current_filter(), array( $this, 'setup_vars' ), 20 );
        add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', array( $this, 'get_select' ) );
        add_filter( "manage_taxonomies_for_attachment_columns", array( $this, 'add_columns' ) );
    }

    public function setup_vars()
    {
        $this->post_type = 'attachment';
        $this->taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $this->post_type );
    }

    public function add_columns( $taxonomies )
    {
        return array_merge(
             $taxonomies
            ,$this->taxonomies
        );
    }

    public function get_select()
    {
        $walker = new WCMF_walker;
        foreach ( $this->taxonomies as $tax )
        {
            wp_dropdown_categories( array(
                 'taxonomy'        => $tax
                ,'hide_if_empty'   => false
                ,'show_option_all' => sprintf(
                     get_taxonomy( $tax )->labels->all_items
                 )
                ,'hide_empty'      => false
                ,'hierarchical'    => is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $tax )
                ,'show_count'      => false
                ,'orderby'         => 'name'
                ,'selected'        => '0' !== get_query_var( $tax )
                    ? get_query_var( $tax )
                    : false
                ,'name'            => $tax
                ,'id'              => $tax
                ,'walker'          => $walker
            ) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add the parent post type as an attachment category
     * 
     * @author Rodolfo Buaiz
     */
    public function auto_tax( $post_id ) 
    {
        $the_p = get_post( $post_id );
        if( $the_p->post_parent > 0 ) 
        {
            $cpt = get_post_type( $the_p->post_parent );
            $term = term_exists( $cpt, 'attachment_category' );
            if( !$term )
                $term = wp_insert_term( $cpt, 'attachment_category' );

            wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term['term_id'], 'attachment_category', true );
        }
    }
} // end BUELTGE/KAISER/RUDOLF

// KAISER
class WCMF_walker extends Walker_CategoryDropdown
{
    var $tree_type = 'category';
    var $db_fields = array(
         'parent' => 'parent'
        ,'id'     => 'term_id'
    );
    public $tax_name;

    /**
     * @see   Walker::start_el()
     * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param  object $term   Taxonomy term data object.
     * @param  int    $depth  Depth of category. Used for padding.
     * @param  array  $args   Uses 'selected' and 'show_count' keys, if they exist.
     * @param  int    $id
     * @return void
     */
    function start_el( &$output, $term, $depth, $args, $id = 0 )
    {
        $pad = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', $depth * 3 );
        $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $term->name, $term );

        $output .= sprintf(
             '<option class="level-%s" value="%s" %s>%s%s</option>'
            ,$depth
            ,$term->slug
            ,selected(
                 $args['selected']
                ,$term->slug
                ,false
             )
            ,"{$pad}{$cat_name}"
            ,$args['show_count']
                ? "&nbsp;&nbsp;({$term->count})"
                : ''
        );
    }
}
// end KAISER
```

Comment: I think now it is good idea, that you create a Github repo and we can help to maintenance the solution. It is easier to use it and create custom enhancements.

Answer (score -1):

My [Media Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-categories-2/) plugin will do this for you - it even cleans up the interface on the Media Modal so you still get the list of checkboxes, by default all you get is text fields.