# categories on attachment page

Tags: categories, media-library

I am using this function to display categories specified to a post having gallery  on the image attachment page.

```
<p>CATEGORY: <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
```

The problem is that this function doesn't return anything. I have also used this way to display categories but no success:

```
    <?php $categories = get_the_category();
          $separator = ', ';
          $output = ''; 
          if($categories){ ?>
          <span>CATERGORY:</span>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category) {
    $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
        }
    echo trim($output, $separator);
        }
        ?>
```

Can anyone tell where problem lies???

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have Categories enabled for your Medialibrary?

Comment: Where I can find that??

Comment: You can try a Plugin like [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-category-library/)

Comment: thanks fischi but I want to do this without using plugins.

Comment: Out of the Box, WordPress does not support Categories for your Media Library. You will have to use or make a Plugin for this, and putting it into your `functions.php` is not recommended as this is not a Themespecific feature.

Comment: I am using twenty eleven

Comment: It does not matter which theme you use - as long as you can not assign Categories to your Images the above function will not work.

Comment: Ok, fischi got it,, but can I do it by some other way like showing categories of its parent post on attachment page?

Comment: something like this:
<p>CATEGORY: <?php the_category(', ', ,$post->post_parent); ?></p>

Comment: Of course, should be no problem. Just be sure to pass the right $post->post_parent.

Comment: It is still not showing!!

Comment: What is the value of your `$post->post_parent`?

Comment: value like,? It is just showing CATEGORY:

Comment: This only returns a value if your $post->post_parent that you pass to the `the_category` function has an integer value, and the associated post_parent has a category. So, what value has your $post->post_parent that you pass to the function? you can `echo` it and see what is in there.

Comment: It is showing 36

Comment: and which categories are associated with this post?

Comment: I  made cat1, cat2, cat3 as categories

Comment: Anyone there, to tell, done all sorts of experiments but still no result. Is there some other way??

Comment: Use the search of wpse or Google, the answer is often to read or use my small answer with the link to a solution to use taxonomies on media's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have **WordPress 3.5** this will work.

http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/attachment-editing-now-with-full-post-edit-ui/

First you need to enable this in your theme, Put this in your functions.php file in your theme root.

```
add_action('init', 'wpse_77390_enable_media_categories' , 1);
function wpse_77390_enable_media_categories() {
   register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'attachment');
}
```

In your image.php or attachments.php file add:

```
$tax = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'category' );
echo $tax;
```

Then go and add some categories to a attachment.

Comment: Thanks Pontus, its working but I want to show parent post category on image.php, I have tried mostly all ways. Can you tell where problem lies??

Answer (score 1):

See the question / answer on this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76720/how-it-is-possible-to-use-taxonomies-on-attachments). 
The answer have 2 different solutions, easy with default categories and taxonomies and also a solution with custom taxonomies only for media.

Comment: Bueltge, what I am trying to say is I want to show parent post category on attachment page here is the link, check this out as it is currently showing:http://i.imgur.com/QNCw9.jpg
I can't individually add categories and taxonomies to all images, as my single post will consist of 50-70 photos as gallery.Is there a way, attachment images can fetch categories from parent post where it is uploaded as:http://i.imgur.com/6wrrw.jpg, or just able to show parent post category directly using code in image.php .

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, now it is clearly for me.