# Taxonomies for Wordpress Media Library

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, media-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How it is possible to use taxonomies on attachments?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76720/how-it-is-possible-to-use-taxonomies-on-attachments)

I know this has been a long debated issue with WP, but I was hoping that since the 3.5 upgrade, there has been some progress in categorizing images in the Media Library.

Really, what I am hoping to accomplish is creating a set of categories for the images in the Media Library, and then assigning the current images, or future images, to those categories.

Then, later down the road I could call them in a page template based on their category.  Any ideas WPA?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the question / answer on this [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76720/how-it-is-possible-to-use-taxonomies-on-attachments). 
The answer have 2 different solutions, easy with default categories and taxonomies and also a solution with custom taxonomies only for media.

Comment: I'm being lousy for checking for duplicates, it seems that they are exact, I'll vote to close this one.

Comment: No problem, the question is very often, duplicate with different words. Not easy for moderators. Best for you.

Comment: Appreciate the help fellas.  I just never associated images/media = attachments, simply because you can just upload media through the library and never use the post editor to do so.  I dunno, either way, this is what I'm looking for.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A starting point, adding the default category to the attachment post type:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_77550_media_categories' );

function wpse_77550_media_categories()
{   
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
```

Or adding a custom taxonomy to the attachment post type (not sure why the taxonomy doesn't show up in the Media menu -`show_ui=>true`-, although the meta box shows up when editing an attachment):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_77550_media_taxonomy' );

function wpse_77550_media_taxonomy()
{   
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Genres', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Genre', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Genres' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Genres' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Genre' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Genre:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Genre' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Genre' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Genre' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Genre Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Genre' ),
      );    

      register_taxonomy('genre','attachment', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
      ));
}
```

*Reference:*
[How To: Add Taxonomies to Your Custom Post Types in WordPress](http://kovshenin.com/2012/how-to-add-taxonomies-to-your-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/)